# Test setup for 200 iterations

Tags: appium, robotframework

I'm doing an Android app test with Appium. The test is configured for 200 iterations and is meant to test the process of updating an external hardware component that the app is BT connected to:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Very Long Test
    FOR  ${i}  IN RANGE  200
        TRY
            Doing testing...
        EXCEPT
            Increment a variable signifying the number of fails...
        ELSE
            Increment a variable signifying the number of successes
        FINALLY
            Cleanup of appdata etc..
        END
    END
```

I've used the **try/except/else/finally** structure to avoid having the whole test abort due to some error caused by navigating the gui of the app or something else irrelevant to the test.

But the test is estimated to take 2 days and having the test run for 5 hours and then seeing a registered failure, I'd really like to get some insight into what caused it without aborting the test.

I understand it's not possible to have a log file generated manually after each iteration, but are there any other solutions available that I can use to just give an indication of what caused the exception to trigger?

Answer (score 0):

1. One of the options could be adding a keyword to `FINALLY` block, that writes to a custom log file a record if the current iteration fails:

```
TRY
   ...
   ${status}  set variable  PASSED
EXCEPT
   ...
   ${status}  set variable  FAILED
FINALLY
   IF  $status == 'FAILED'  append to file  ${file_path}  ${iteration_info}\n
```

2. Each iteration looks like a standalone test, so there could be an approrach to move the iteration body to a templated test, that could be repeated for different data samples. Robot Framework has some option for that:

[Test Template](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#test-templates)

[Data Driven](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#different-test-case-styles)

etc